# Could someone help me about to create a posix regex?

Tags: java, regex, postgresql, posix-ere

could someone help me to create a posix regex which checks if the entered string follows the following pattern:

> Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday

Or

> Monday, Wednesday, Friday

Or

> Sunday

Then:

1. Days of the week followed by ", "
2. I can't repeat a day of the week
3. The last day of a string must not have ", "

Comment: Yes, if you try something and have a problem which you demonstrate here with code and describe in detail, then you will surely find help here. For easy tinkering try https://regex101.com Generally please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I just don't know how to do it, so how could I explain it??

Answer (score 0):

If the order of days doesn't matter, use:

```
^((Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)(, (?!$)(?!.*\2)|$))*$
```

See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/7QetOc/2).

Explanation:

- The inner parenthesis are used for expressing the disjunction of days.
- `^` matches the begin of the string.
- `$` matches the end of the string.
- `(?!$)` means that comma must not be follwed by the end of string.
- `(?!.*\2)` means not followed by any number of characters (`.*`) and the second group (`\2`), that is the innermost one.

About the last point, I suggest you to google about regex matching groups, lookarounds backreferences

Comment: helping someone to do his/her homework is the best way to make him/her lazier and more dependent.

Comment: @Joe he explained how he did it, and I've understood, so idk what's the problem...
however, thank you very much horcrux